# Randomize numbers in Lua with no repeats

Tags: random, lua

I am doing a project in Lua which involves randomizing numbers without repeats. Here's my code

```
for i = 1, 86000 do
    while rndom[num] ~= nil do
        num = math.random(1,95000)
     end
     rndom[num] = num
     for k=1, 11 do
        file2:write(input[num][k], " ")
     end
     file2:write("\n")
end
```

Basically it puts a value to the rndom[num] so that when randomized number repeats and rndom[num] ~= nil, it will randomize number again. My problem is, it's taking too long to load as my 'i' gets higher and there will come a time that it will stop. I'm guessing it's because randomizer can't get a rndom[num] that's 'nil'. I mean, what are the odds right? I'd like to improve the running time of it. Anyone who can suggest a better solution to my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to generate a permutation with `O(N)` time complexity.

```
local n = 95000

local t = {}
for i = 1, n do
   t[i] = i
end

for i = 1, 86000 do
   local j = math.random(i, n)
   t[i], t[j] = t[j], t[i]
   for k = 1, 11 do
      file2:write(input[t[i]][k], " ")
   end
   file2:write"\n"
end
```

Comment: wow. that did it! It definitely made the running time faster. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is instead of using `random` again when you get a variable you already have, trying to return the next one available. That way you are guaranteed to have `O(N^2)` running time (maximum).

Comment: oh. you mean the next number to the randomized number that repeats?

Comment: Exactly. So, if you random 5, mark it. After you random 5 again, try if 6 was taken. If not, return it. Just remember to wrap after you reach maximum.